# Elasticsearch 1.7 backup error, "Error injecting constructor"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single node, local ES set up on my mac, and I'm trying to create a snapshot (the whole thing is for migrating data to 2.x version)

I'm trying to use the /User/Shared as the path to store the snapshot as I know it should be accessible to everyone

My path.repo in elasticsearch.yml is set to be

`path.repo: ["/Users/Shared/es_backup","/mount/backups", "/mount/longterm_backups"]`

where I manually created a folder (chmod to 777) called es_backup.

Now when I run:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_backup' -d '{
    "type":"fs", 
    "setting":{
        "compress": true, 
        "location": "/Users/Shared/es_backup"}}'
```

It is throwing me the error:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, 
    org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoryException: [es_backup] missing location
    at org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository.<init>(Unknown Source)
    while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository
    while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository
```

As I mentioned, I've actually seen quite a few threads talking about the same error, and it always points to permission issue. I've set everything to 777 but this still occurs.

When running `curl "locatinhost:9200/_nodes/settings?pretty"` I get:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "<some_name>",
  "nodes" : {
    "W0SRjd24Tfq1_S8UPegNlA" : {
      "name" : "Flash Thompson",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]",
      "host" : "<some_host>",
      "ip" : "10.1.2.39",
      "version" : "1.7.5",
      "build" : "00f95f4",
      "http_address" : "inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]",
      "settings" : {
        "path" : {
          "data" : "/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/",
          "logs" : "/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch",
          "plugins" : "/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins",
          "home" : "/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch17/1.7.5",
          "repo" : [ "/Users/Shared/es_backup", "/mount/backups", "/mount/longterm_backups" ]
        },
        "cluster" : {
          "name" : "<some_name>"
        },
        "name" : "Flash Thompson",
        "client" : {
          "type" : "node"
        },
        "foreground" : "yes",
        "config" : {
          "ignore_system_properties" : "true"
        },
        "network" : {
          "host" : "127.0.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where some_name and some_host are my cluster name and my machine.

I know my setting is applied correctly as the repo part clearly shows my path where I want to store the snapshot.

So I'm wondering what I've done wrong, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it turns out there's some issue when I try to set path.repo for a path other than default. When I try setting the location to /mount/backups/my_backup everything works nicely.